# SharePoint Designer 2007 - link to a Document Library on a site from another site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to create a link to an existing Shared Documents folder on another site.  Both sites are on the same server.

Here are the steps I take to create a link to an existing Document Library:

1. I create a document library web page in Share Point 2007.
2. I open the document library (AllItems.ASPX) in Share Point Designer.
3. I delete the existing web part for the list.
4. In the Data Source Library, I click on "connect to another library" and create a connection to the other site.
5. I select the document library, click show data, select my rows and click Insert Multiple Item View.
6. I then configure the look for each field (hyperlinks, etc).
7. I edit the Filter for this view to show only the files that are for this location.
8. I click on Data View Properties and select "Enable sorting and filtering on columns (basic table layout only).

Basically I am trying to have a central location for all files for a site and sub sites.  I want the sub sites to see the documents for their own location, be able to search through the files, etc.

The problems I am having are:

1. I am unable to open the links in a new window, even when I set the hyperlink to do so. I would prefer the file be opened in its native application (ie. A Word doc open in Word).
2. I am unable to show the file icon in the same way it shows up in the original document library.
3. When I go to the header and click ANY field, I can sort the field ascending or descending but I always get a message stating "This column type cannot be filtered".

Is there an easier way to do this?  Or can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am new to using Share Point.   Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Some help for problem 1 (unable to open the links in a new window)...

I'm not sure if this will work using the Data View Web Part you have configured. However there is a technique for the List View Web Part. If you add a boolean field called `OpenInNewWindow` to your document library then documents that have this set to Yes will open in a new window. Try this out - it may work.

If you need to open PDF files in a new window, beware that there is an ActiveX control that will get in the way. [Read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174842/sharepoint-open-document-library-pdf-in-new-window) for more information.